# Smooth Scrolling doesn't Work when html and body height is 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my css for index page

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Here is my smooth Scroll Script

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

and my main content is in wrap id and header is outside of wrap id

Comment: But you have a scrollable element, right? Do the smooth scroll on it..

Comment: You're trying to scroll `$('html, body')` while you're pretty explicit about those not being the scroll-container.

Comment: because there is nothing to scroll, your content is for sure overflowing the body with this setting

Comment: Update this ` $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top},  1000);` , instead oh putting html and body, add the next element after `#wrap`